Electric Field due to Finite Sheet of Charge - Find the minimum width and height to assume infinite sheet of charge
One can find that the electric field due to a sheet of charge of finite dimensions can be defined as (modified from Physics stack exchange):
$$
E = \frac{\rho_s}{2\epsilon} \cdot \frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{ab}{4r \sqrt{ \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{b}{2} \right)^2 + r^2 }} \right)
$$
where $r$ is the perpendicular distance from the sheet; $a$ and $b$ are the dimensions of the sheet.
I have seen that this can be represented as $E = \frac{\rho_s}{2\epsilon}$, when a and b approach infinity (for example, see page 65 in the book Electromagnetics for Engineers - Clayton Paul).
I want to model a charged sheet on the software "CST" (dimensions must be finite) and want to set a and b such that the sheet can be modelled as effectively infinitely wide/long for a known value $r$.
To find the optimal dimensions, I want to plot the following function on a graph and find the value of $a$ and $b$ (or the relationship between $a$ and $b$) where $f(a,b)$ is close enough to one. But there are two independent variables here:
$$
f(a,b)=\frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{ab}{4r \sqrt{ \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{b}{2} \right)^2 + r^2 }} \right)
$$
How should such an optimisation be done? Is there a way to rearrange/substitute the equation above to be in terms of one variable only?

What you want is to make the argument of $\tan^{-1}$ large enough. I'll come back at how large. But I will rewrite it first as
$$\frac{ab}{4r\sqrt{\frac{a^2}4+\frac{b^2}4+r^2}}=\frac{ab}{4r^2\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4r^2}+\frac{b^2}{4r^2}+1}}=\frac{\frac a{2r}\frac b{2r}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac a{2r}\right)^2+\left(\frac b{2r}\right)^2+1}}$$
It is easy to see that your function depends on $\frac a{2r}$ and $\frac b{2r}$. This make sense: if I move further away from the sheet, I need to make the sheet dimensions proportionally larger.
The other thing that you should notice is that there is a symmetry between the $a$ and $b$ directions. If you keep the area of the sheet constant ($ab$ is constant) then the smallest value for the denominator occurs when $a=b$. What that means is you want to use a square sheet. Using $x=\frac a{2r}$, you get $$f(x)=\frac2\pi\tan^{-1}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}$$
If you set $f(x)=c\approx 1$ you can easily calculate $x$:
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}=\tan\frac{\pi c}2$$
$$(x^2)^2=\tan^2\frac{\pi c}2(2x^2+1)$$
This is a quadratic in $x^2$. You need to choose the positive solution.
The graph of $f(x)$ looks like this
